# Deserialize to Apex Object

Tags: apex, json

For example I have following Apex class:

```
public class ToDeserialize {

    public Wrapper Wrapper;

    public class Wrapper {
        public Long myLong; 
    }
}
```

And I have JSON which I want to deserialize to the ToDeserialize object:

```
'{"Wrapper": {"myLong": null} }'
```

Then I'm trying to deserialize it and it works fine and print myLong to System.debug:

```
ToDeserialize result = (ToDeserialize) JSON.deserialize(result, ToDeserialize.class);
Long var = result.wrapper.myLong;
System.debug(var);
```

But when I'm trying to assure that var is instance of Long I'm getting following error:

```
System.debug(var instanceof Long);
Operation instanceof is always false since an instance of String is never an instance of Long
```

What the reason? And what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I've tried your example and haven't faced the same result, and the result was as expected: `Operation instanceof is always true since an instance of Long is always an instance of Long`. You might have missed something.

Comment: @OlehBerehovskyi Yes my real code is much complicated and the Long variable is inside another object in JSON and a little changed example. Probably problem is that Long variable is inside another object

Comment: Can you try `var instanceof Decimal`? I'm guessing apex is not differiating numerical types. Another suggestion is to change the variable name, eg `myvar`.

Comment: I've even tried your updated wrapper with inner class deser and I'm still having `Operation instanceof is always true since an instance of Long is always an instance of Long`

Comment: Your code is incorrect, as `wrapper` does not exist as a variable. You may have oversimplified your code. As written, we expect a compiler error that a Long is a Long, because a Long is a Long, and you can't make trivial comparisons using instanceOf.